# How to calculate the amount of fuel required and time to preheat a furnace's combustion air to 850 C

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering, combustion

I am designing an incinerator to combust MSW producing a flue gas of 1000 °C. A requirement of the furnace is that the air inside must be preheated to 850 °C through the use of auxiliary fuel burners before waste can be fed in.

I have assumed that the air flow rate required to combust the MSW would remain the same and I have calculated the amount of diesel required per hour to achieve a flue gas temperature of 850 °C. However, I am unsure of the time the auxiliary burners need to be fired for to heat the furnace up to the required temperature.

I also have the furnace volume if that is required?

Comment: What are the relative masses of flue gas and fresh air ? Nat gas is easier to handle than oil which may need atomization. Cook Co ( Chicago) Sanitary district did work on burning garbage starting in the 60's and may have published information you can apply.

Comment: Is there a simple formula I can apply though?

Comment: there is no simple formula for this.  You can't just heat the air inside the furnace, there is constant turnover.

Comment: What procedure do you recommend taking then?

Comment: I recommend a temperature sensor.  there are thermocouples capable of operating at that temperature and hotter.